# How to select columns from joined?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5.8

How to select columns from joined?

```
$this->select('c.CurLevel''rl.Exp_C')->join($this->getData('sqlsrv3').'.dbo._RefLevel AS rl', 'c.CurLevel', '=', 'rl.Lvl+1');
```

How can I do `rl.Level+1`

Answer (score 0):

select the column previous table nick name:

```
$this->select(['c.CurLevel','rl.Exp_C'])
->join($this->getData('sqlsrv3').'.dbo._RefLevel AS rl', 'c.CurLevel', '=', 'rl.Lvl+1');
```